# Is it true that $\delta$ is a Lebesgue number for the given cover?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. Suppose an open cover of $X$ is given. Let $\{U_i\}_i$ be an its finite subcover. Consider the following function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $x\mapsto \max\{d(x,U_i^c)\}_i$. Say $\delta=\min\{f(x):x\in X\}$. Is it true that $\delta$ is a Lebesgue number for the given cover? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. 
First of all, you must prove $f$ is continuos. This follows from triangle inequality, since for all $x,y \in X$ we have 
$$
d\left(x,U^c_i\right) \le d(x,y)+ d\left(y,U^c_i\right).$
$$

Now you must assure that your $\delta$ is not zero. But, since $U_i$'s are open and cover $X$, for all $x\in X$, $x$ belong to some $U_i$ for some $i$. Then, there exists $\epsilon$ such that the ball $B(x,\epsilon) \subset U_i$ which implies $f(x) \ge d(x, U_i^c) \ge \epsilon.$

This proves that $\delta >0$.

Now, let $B$ be a subset of $X$ of diameter less than $\delta$ and $x\in B$. Suppose $f(x) = d(x,U_m^c)$ for some $m$. Thus $d(x,z) \ge \delta$ for all $z\in U_m^c$. Since $diam(B) < \delta$ this implies $d(x,y) < \delta$ for all $y \in B$. This assures that $y$ mustn't lie in $U_m^c$ which concludes the proof.